# Wait until firebase gets the data to move on (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have a function that returns a value that I get from firebase but Asynchronous programming is making it super hard. I want to be able to wait until (points != -500). However every time I try to wait, it seems to stop the task of getting the points value from firebase as well.

I can hard-code it to wait 3 seconds, but I would much prefer to check every half-second to see if the points value has changed, *then* return the value I got from the database. I also know that I can retrieve points from the text view that I changed, but I feel like that interrupts the integrity of my application.

Here's the code I'm working with

```
getPoints() {
    var points= "-500"
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Edit").child(storeName).child(
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    )

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            points= snapshot.child("points").value.toString()
            pointsNumberTextView.text = points
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Err 11 Database reach cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
 //wait until (points != 500) then return points
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous execution is not an option, but one can use a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/Query) to accomplish this:

```
ref.child("points").orderByValue().startAt("-500").endAt("500")
```

It's just a bit difficult to tell for certain, because there is no sample data;
this at least should push you into the right direction, I hope.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. The snapshot.child("Points").value.toString() would return a value of anywhere from 1 to 50 (That is what will be stored in the database).

Comment: So if that points value was "25" I would want to wait until it grabs the points from the database and then return "25". I kind of want to mimic a synchronous action in a way.